# Can't login into gnome shell using lightdm or gdm

Tags: gnome, login

Good Morning, I have one problem trying to login into gnome shell since today, When I try to login it returns me back to the login screen, I tried using gdm and lightdm, but any of them works, Unity works normally.

What could be the problem?

I just upgrade the system yesterday, and the only packages somekind related were lightdm and lightdm-gobject-1-0.
I also changed the system's language a weeks ago, but It was working normally, just after yesterday's update the problem appeared.
Thank you